# Are there open source web browsers implemented in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, browser, binding, open-source

Are there any open source web browsers implemented in Ruby?  If not, are there any Ruby bindings, preferably cross-platform and actively maintained, to open source rendering engines such as Gecko and/or Webkit?  My google searches aren't revealing much, so I'm asking here in case somebody who is more in the know as to the Ruby eco-system, since I've only been dabbling with it the past couple of months.

EDIT: In response to question as to whether browser should be headless or not, I would say *not*.  What I'm trying to develop is a desktop ebook reader that supports Javascript, where I can launch a web server on the desktop, then point this browser at it to serve as the UI for the application.  Actually I've made much progress toward this with another language (Tcl) and an open source browser written in Tcl (Hv3), but am interested in porting to Ruby for visibility purposes.

Comment: Should the browser be headless or not?

Comment: Not.  I thought about describing what I'm trying to do in the question.  I will do so now.

Comment: If I understand correctly, basically you want to adapt something like luakit (http://luakit.org) but in Ruby?

Comment: Actually I'm not opposed to doing this with Lua with which I've tinkered so thanks for that.  Lua might have less visibility than Tcl, but really what I'm seeking is a more up-to-date rendering platform than Hv3 which is still alpha, un-maintained, and so won't be supporting HTML5.  It helped me get up and running remarkably quickly, but it's probably time to move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings to web rendering components are usually in the scope of GUI toolkits. There's [Gtk MozEmbed](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3a%3aMozEmbed), [several](https://github.com/danlucraft/rbwebkitgtk) [bindings](https://github.com/geoffyoungs/gtk-webkit-ruby) to Gtk WebKit, and [QtRuby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/korundum/) should also have access to QtWebKit.

Comment: I'd found some of the other bindings you suggest but, correct me if I'm wrong, they don't seem like they're being actively maintained.  Thanks for the QtRuby/QtWebKit suggestion though

Comment: By the way, I've taken your QtRuby/QtWebKit suggestion quite far in the meantime, even packaging it as an executable with OCRA (One Click Ruby Application) but that step seems to cause McAfee to think it's a virus.  Nothwithstanding, if interested in the steps I took, please see: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150123-Windows-Desktop-App-using-Ruby-(instead-of-AIR)